# How to train CNN models with additional categorical / numerical features?

Tags: tensorflow

In addition to the image itself in RGB, I also have a list of metadata / categorical / numerical features attached each image.

e.g. Local time of day, day of week of when the photo was taken, GPS / city name of the photo, and a brief description of the photo (written by human).

How do you train a CNN model using tensorflow with additional features?

Answer (score 0):

Generally, it is a hard problem to flexibly include all various features (images, time, description etc) into one model. CNN is designed for and only for extracting information from images. The operations like convolution, pooling can only be applied to images and require a lot of efforts to design generalizations.

However, CNN does help you summarize the information contained in an image. You could use the prediction of your CNN as your features and feed in another model.

Comment: That means sense. So I would use the output of the CNN model and feed into another model, along side with other categorical or continuous features to make predictions. However, what would you use as the label for the CNN model? In other words, what is the CNN model predicting?

Comment: Using ResNet, you can assign a label to the picture; using Fast-RCNN, you can detect objects in a video. There are too many things to do with CNN so there's not a one-for-all answer. It really depends on your application.